# Can I time travel to the next time a villager asks to move out or do I have to play the whole 15 days

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I’m trying to get entirely new villagers on my island, but it's a 15 day period between the time a new villager moves in and an old villager asks to move out. I’m wondering if I could time travel to the 15th day or if I have to play all the days in-between?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out: You have to play each day. You have to go on your island, walk around for a minute or so, then Save and Quit.

Do this for 15 days and the bubble will appear.